# Crystal Report Portuguese language support

Tags: iis, crystal-reports, internationalization

Hi I am using Crystal Reports 10 with IIS Server. I wish to display some of the reports in Portuguese language. How can I configure Crystal Reports to display data in Portuguese ? I guess I will need to download a language pack for this but will it allow word-by-word conversion from English to Portuguese ? Grammatically correct sentences are not currently my concern. Any inputs will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To localize the labels, try this approach: [Crystal Reports: Strategy to Localize a Report (labels)](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2009/07/09/crystal-reports-strategy-to-localize-a-report-labels/)

If you need to localize the data, you will need to try one of the following approaches:

- write a user-function library (UFL) that accepts the TABLE.FIELD that you want to translate and returns the translated text.  You would reference this custom function in a formula field.  In the UFL, you can make a call to a service like [Babel Fish](http://babelfish.yahoo.com/) or use another library that will do the translation.
- Store the translated text in another field and simply reference it in a formula field.  You might be able to use the CR's ContentLocale function to dynamically determine the workstation's language.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports can't translate the data of a report. If you want that you should define those translations yourself in your report's definitions, like by using formulas.

Comment: I can use formula only for static content, for the dynamic content which is coming from Oracle I wish I can translate it somehow in CR. I don't wish to recreate DB with Portuguese language support.